# Hive Table Error loading json data

Tags: json, hadoop

json file:

```
{
    "DocId":"ABC",
    "User":{
        "Id":1234,
        "Username":"sam1234",
        "Name":"Sam",
        "ShippingAddress":{
            "Address1":"123 Main St.",
            "Address2":null,
            "City":"Durham",
            "State":"NC"
        },
        "Orders":[{
                "ItemId":6789,
                "OrderDate":"11/11/2012"
            },
            {
                "ItemId":4352,
                "OrderDate":"12/12/2012"
            }
        ]
    }
}}
```

schema:

```
create external table sample_json(DocId string,User struct<Id:int,Username:string,Name:string,ShippingAddress:struct<Address1:string,Address2:string,City:string,State:string>,Orders:array<struct<ItemId:int,OrderDate:string>>>)ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' location '/user/babu/sample_json';
```

--loading data to the hive table

load data inpath '/user/samplejson/samplejson.json' into table sample_json;

Error:

when I am firing the select query like

```
select * from sample_json;
```

Exception:

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException:
>   org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input:
>   expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source:
>   java.io.StringReader@8c3770; line: 1, column: 0])  at [Source:
>   java.io.StringReader@8c3770; line: 1, column: 3]

Comment: Your example shows unbalanced `{ }` because of the double `}}` on the end. But I'm not a JSON expert...

Answer (score 0):

First please ensure that json file is valid through http://jsonlint.com and then remove any newline characters or unwanted spaces in the json file before loading the file into the hive table. Also please drop the table and create a new table if you have already loaded json files having newline characters into the table.

Following is the input you can try

```
{"DocId":"ABC",
 "User":{"Id":1234,
         "Username":"sam1234",
          "Name":"Sam",
          "ShippingAddress":{"Address1":"123 Main St.","Address2":null,"City":"Durham","State":"NC"},
 "Orders":[{"ItemId":6789,"OrderDate":"11/11/2012"}, 
           {"ItemId":4352,"OrderDate":"12/12/2012"}
          ]
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the newline from the json file.

{"DocId": "ABC", "Userdetails": {"Id": 1234, "Username": "sam1234", "Name": "Sam", "ShippingAddress": {"Address1": "123 Main St.", "Address2": null, "City": "Durham", "State": "NC" }, "Orders":[{"ItemId": 6789, "OrderDate": "11/11/2012"}, {"ItemId": 4352, "OrderDate": "12/12/2012"}]}}

2. change User to userdetails as it's a identifier check the error which I got.
   3.either use location or load data inpath. because both does the same work. Location does not create a folder in HDFS while load inpath does create folder.

[image]

following are the commands :

## hive>

create external table sample_json(DocId string, userdetails struct< Id:int , Username:string,Name:string,ShippingAddress:struct,Orders:array< struct< ItemId:int, OrderDate:string>>>)ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' location '/user/admin';
OK
Time taken: 0.13 seconds

## hive>

select * from sample_json;
OK
sample_json.docid       sample_json.userdetails
ABC     {"id":1234,"username":"sam1234","name":"Sam","shippingaddress":{"address1":"123 Main St.","address2":null,"city":"Durham","state":"NC"},"orders":[{"itemid":6789,"orderdate":"11/11/2012"},{"itemid":4352,"orderdate":"12/12/2012"}]}
Time taken: 0.106 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

[image]